# Seperate Table values with "/" in LUA

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a table = `{1, 2, 3}`

Now i want to print everything in the table **but seperated with "/"** meaning my result should be `1/2/3` The problem is that my table constantly updates and sometimes it changes to `{1, 3}` or even just `{2}` so how can i print everything in the table but each value seperated by a "/" without ending like one of the following:

`1//3`

`13`

`1/3/`

but instead:

`1/3`

Comment: `a={1, 2, 3} print(table.concat(a,"/"))`.

Comment: Normally Lua doesn't have parallelism. What platform is your Lua embedded in? Use that to "lock" your table to ensure it doesn't change while you're printing it, as [inserting new value is "undefined behavior"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167555/how-can-i-safely-iterate-a-lua-table-while-keys-are-being-removed).